# Displaying ASCII-art in TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to develop an offline version of Candy box (solely for personal use only) using Tkinter and the ASCII art won't display properly on Tkinter Canvas.

This is the way I'd like it to be displayed:

```
"""
        .---.
       |   '.|  __
       | ___.--'  )
     _.-'_` _%%%_/
  .-'%%% a: a %%%
      %%  L   %%_
      _%\'-' |  /-.__
   .-' / )--' #/     '\
  /'  /  /---'(    :   \
 /   |  /( /|##|  \     |
/   ||# | / | /|   \    \
|   ||##| I \/ |   |   _|
|   ||: | o  |#|   |  / |
|   ||  / I  |:/  /   |/
|   ||  | o   /  /    /
|   \|  | I  |. /    /
 \  /|##| o  |.|    /
  \/ \::|/\_ /  ---'|
  """)
```

And this is the way it is displayed (I've attempted changing the font to what is used in IDLE (Courier, 10), because it seemed to display correctly, however it didn't seem to help.

Using the following code, this is what it ended up looking like:

```
self.merchantShow = Tk.Label(self, font=self.fontused, text=
"""
        .---.
       |   '.|  __
       | ___.--'  )
     _.-'_` _%%%_/
  .-'%%% a: a %%%
      %%  L   %%_
      _%\'-' |  /-.__
   .-' / )--' #/     '\
  /'  /  /---'(    :   \
 /   |  /( /|##|  \     |
/   ||# | / | /|   \    \
|   ||##| I \/ |   |   _|
|   ||: | o  |#|   |  / |
|   ||  / I  |:/  /   |/
|   ||  | o   /  /    /
|   \|  | I  |. /    /
 \  /|##| o  |.|    /
  \/ \::|/\_ /  ---'|
  """)
            self.merchantShow.grid(row=4, column=0, stick="W")
```

[image: Failed Art]

Can somebody please help me solve this and explain why this is happening? I'm assuming it has something to do with the font, but I'm sure there's got to be an easier way than going through all the fonts.

Comment: Just a hint, you can use any monospace font and it will work. Courier is a good choice, but there are others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Align text to left (center is default)
2. Backslash at the line end have a special meaning in python: it wraps long lines. Use [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

```
from tkinter import *

text = r"""
        .---.
       |   '.|  __
       | ___.--'  )
     _.-'_` _%%%_/
  .-'%%% a: a %%%
      %%  L   %%_
      _%\'-' |  /-.__
   .-' / )--' #/     '\
  /'  /  /---'(    :   \
 /   |  /( /|##|  \     |
/   ||# | / | /|   \    \
|   ||##| I \/ |   |   _|
|   ||: | o  |#|   |  / |
|   ||  / I  |:/  /   |/
|   ||  | o   /  /    /
|   \|  | I  |. /    /
 \  /|##| o  |.|    /
  \/ \::|/\_ /  ---'|
  """

root = Tk()
Label(root, justify=LEFT, text=text).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I am using python 2.7.3 and `justify=LEFT` is returning a name error. I know this is terribly noob but I don't know why. I've been googling for the last half an hour.

Comment: I assume that you import tkinter with line `import Tkinter as Tk`. So, use `Tk.LEFT`

Comment: ah, my bad. I thought of this, but used `Tk.justify` :I Cheers ^_^