# ASCII art in Tkinter doesn't look like in console

Tags: python, tkinter, format, ascii-art

I have this Python(3.7.2) code:

```
 import tkinter as tk
 root = tk.Tk()

 art = '''

                 uu$$$$$$$$$$$uu
              uu$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$uu
             u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u
            u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u
           u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u
           u$$$$$$*   *$$$*   *$$$$$$u
           *$$$$*      u$u       $$$$*
            $$$u       u$u       u$$$
            $$$u      u$$$u      u$$$
             *$$$$uu$$$   $$$uu$$$$*
              *$$$$$$$*   *$$$$$$$*
                u$$$$$$$u$$$$$$$u
                 u$*$*$*$*$*$*$u
      uuu        $$u$ $ $ $ $u$$       uuu
      u$$$$       $$$$$u$u$u$$$       u$$$$
      $$$$$uu      *$$$$$$$$$*     uu$$$$$$
    u$$$$$$$$$$$uu    *****    uuuu$$$$$$$$$
    $$$$***$$$$$$$$$$uuu   uu$$$$$$$$$***$$$*
     ***      **$$$$$$$$$$$uu **$***
              uuuu **$$$$$$$$$$uuu
     u$$$uuu$$$$$$$$$uu **$$$$$$$$$$$uuu$$$
     $$$$$$$$$$****           **$$$$$$$$$$$*
       *$$$$$*                      **$$$$**
         $$$*                         $$$$*

'''

print(art)

label = tk.Label(text=art)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It prints the skull in console and in Tkinter. But in Tkinter it's formatted incorrectly. (No errors are thrown)

[image]

**Questions**

1. Why does Tkinter (Label) have another format?
2. How can I fix it?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461843/displaying-ascii-art-in-tkinter) is the only related post, but it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a monospace font for ASCII art to work correctly. Use this for example:

```
import Tkinter
import ttk

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Style.TButton', font='TkFixedFont')

label = tk.Label(text=art, style='Style.TButton')
```